# Would trolling the people behind scams help decrease scamming?

Tags: email

It is easy for smart people to identify scams. This isn't an accident, phishers want stupid people. Sending the emails is the easy part, getting their money is what takes effort.

My question is, being an at least some what smart person, should I respond to scams as a small way to reduce phishing globally? Like, I would respond to the scam, but really be trolling the scammer?

- How does this affect me?

  - Obviously, I don't give them information/give them ridiculous information, so I am not at risk that way
- Would this hurt the scammer very much?

  - If a large number of people did this, would scamming become more expensive/less effective?
- How long could I keep the scammer going before they realize I'm not cooperating?

Comment: http://www.419eater.com/

Comment: I think [phishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing) does not mean what you think it means. A phishing scam usually just sends the user to a fake website to get their login info. It doesn't include any direct interaction.

Comment: @Philipp Whoops, dang.

Comment: @Philipp Exactly. I've tried to correct the post by replacing "phishing" with "scamming" but my edit was rejected. To the OP: please edit the question.

Comment: @dr01 I should probably post a new one.

Comment: @PyRulez No, it's better to edit this question. No need to post a new one. All answers here relate to scamming (and not phishing) anyway.

Comment: The only thing trolling seems to solve is boredom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The website http://www.419eater.com (mentioned also by one commenter) is a community of *scambaiters* that do exactly what you wrote: they bait and troll scammers in order to make them waste their time and forces (and sometimes, even their money).

While this might be fun, and does a good service to the community by spreading the word and alerting against these scammers, I think it will not be very effective as a DoS until a large number of people starts doing scambaiting.  Scammers have a lot of time on their hands, and the reward is pretty big once they manage to find a fool and his money.  If you do this for the fun, fine, go ahead (and post your trophies on 419eater.com!) just don't expect this to have a huge impact.

Instead, a more effective countermeasure is to send a abuse report to the scammer's ISP.  Most scammers use a sender email address and a contact email address exactly for this reason; be sure to send the complaint to both providers.

Comment: On 419eater.com, they also are able to get their bank account numbers apparently. Wouldn't this hurt them more than just taking down their website?

Comment: Also, how do you report them to the ISP?

Comment: send email to `abuse@`{domain-name-of-isp} and/or check the WHOIS record for their domains names and use the contact details found there.

Comment: There is no website, the vast majority of scams is done entirely via email. By complaining to the email provider, you make them lose their mailbox, and often all the traces of the people they're scamming. This is the most effective countermeasure IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

I remember of an interview of someone having even written a book on subject (in French sadly). He explained how he entered the spammer game to appear as the worse complete unbearable moron as possible to them.

The result how I saw them were the following:

- The spammer was just sending standard pre-written emails, one of them was even sent twice during the email exchanges if I remember correctly. The spammer doesn't care of your email nor engaging any conversation with you, so for him it just a matter to quickly check you mail for a few keywords, select the appropriate answer template, and send it to you. Just a dozen of seconds.
- The book author had to take time imagine the most clever answer to produce, the most silly excuse to send, etc. He took this as a game at that moment, so it was not lost time, but it took him quite a bunch time which could have been used elsewhere.

So the answer is as follow: at the end it will take you a lot of time, the spammer will not care, you will just receive template messages in answer to your emails.

Comment: Since you mentioned, can you share the book title?

Comment: @kenorb: Yes, I just managed to find it, it is called *Les milliards de dollars de Léon Robillard* by Vincent Malone. You can read [an article about this book here](http://www.franceinter.fr/oeuvre-les-milliards-de-dollars-de-leon-robillard), initially I heard him on the French radio France Inter, the original program [should be available here](http://www.franceinter.fr/emission-ca-peut-pas-faire-de-mal-speciale-vincent-malone-0).

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can see that would hurt them. but it's easier to attack their infrastructure,

what they are doing is illegal in most places.

Complain to the registrar of their domain, the company who hosts their server. their telephone provider, etc...

those guys will have less patience and have the power to take action.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "attack their infrastructure"? Do you really believe they attack by using registered IPs, domains.. on their own name?

Comment: how can they hope to get your information otherwise.  If they have hijacked someone elses account, closing that denies them of their feedback stream, and revenue.

Comment: Slave machines, compromised websites, VPN, Tor and so on

Comment: all of which are succeptible,

Comment: good luck in reporting all zombies, slave machines, vulnerable websites and so on. The Internet Police!

Comment: How would it hurt them? Can you explain or provide references?

Comment: If they can't receive feedback from potential marks, that'll mess up their business method.